# Saving Data from jQuery/EXT JS

Tags: jquery, extjs

When saving data from a form submit using jQuery/Ext JS what is the best approach?
Should the data be sent as an Array/List or JSON to the Server?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'page',
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            data: ({id: 1, idUser: 000}),
            dataType: "html",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                alert(date);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank u! Ext JS JSON encoding?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your server side system/frameworks etc. For example, if you were sending values to a WCF Web Service, you could configure said web service to expect whatever you fancy sending.

However, saving as URL POST params will remove requirement to decode values on the server side.

IE: If you save as JSON, you'll have to decode that JSON on the server side before you can use the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a EXT JS:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  loadMask: true,
  url: 'myfile.php',
  params: {id: "1"},
  success: function(resp) {
    // resp is the XmlHttpRequest object
    var options = Ext.decode(resp.responseText).options;

    Ext.each(options, function(op) {
      alert(op.message);
    }
  }
});
```